# Renaming multiple files by rearranging the original file name

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to rename multiple files that follow the same naming convention, the only variation is the date at the end of the name.

For example `TRADARCASHROLLUP.GRPTIRHK.01052017.CSV` I would like the new name of the file to begin with the date instead `01052017.TRADARCASHROLLUP.GRPTIRHK.CSV`

Was hoping someone could help me write a batch script to achieve this. I have seen other answers but not been able to apply them to this.

I have tried using the following:

```
ls | %{ "C:\UBSTesting\Incoming\TRADARCASHROLLUP.GRPTIRHK*" $_.name ($_.name 
-replace '^(\w+).(\w+).(\w+)', '$3.$1.$2')}
```

Comment: If you show us what you have tried we can help make that solution work

Comment: [Edit] that into your question so it does not get lost in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you also tagged it `batch-file`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.*.*.csv) do (
  for %%b in (%%~na) do (
    set new=%%~xb.%%~nb%%~xa
    ECHO !new:~1!
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked for me. Is it then possible to then rearrange the date to be YYYY\MM\DD ?

Comment: sure, with some substring processing (see `set /?`). Note: `\` is not a valid character for a filename

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp' | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $_.Name -replace '(.+).(\d{8})', '$2.$1'
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName $newName
}
```