# Rename file by rearranging original name

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a bunch of files all named with the date at the start, for example:

```
30062017.TRADARCASHROLLUP.MCLTIRHK.CSV
```

Is it possible to rearrange this date so instead of DD/MM/YYYY, it will begin with YYYY/MM/DD

Comment: The answer to your question: yes, it is. Please show the attempts you have made and describe what you specifically have troubles with!

Comment: This question appears to be almost the same: [Renaming multiple files by rearranging the original file name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47392342). Please do **not** double-post!

Comment: You keep tagging your questions with PowerShell and batch-file. You should consider just using one or the other.

Comment: Simple with [JREN.BAT - a regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081): `jren "^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d{4})\." "$3$2$1."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
$OldFileName = '30062017.TRADARCASHROLLUP.MCLTIRHK.CSV'    
$NewDateString = ([datetime]::ParseExact($OldFileName.Substring(0,8), "ddMMyyyy", $null)).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$NewFileName = $OldFileName -Replace '^.{8}',$NewDateString

$NewFileName
```

This uses the .NET ParseExact method to convert the first 8 characters of the string in to a datetime object, then uses .ToString to format it in reverse.

Then we use a RegEx replace to replace the first 8 characters of the file name with the new string.

Answer (score 1):

Make the file with this format in powershell:

```
$format1 = '{0:yyyy/MM/dd}' -f (Get-Date)
$format2 = ".TRADARCASHROLLUP.MCLTIRHK.CSV"
$format+$format2
```

Hope it helps.